# rosinstall fails when encountering kforge repos from generated .rosinstall file

Tags: ros, rosinstall, kforge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When issuing the command:

rosinstall ~/Documents/ROS "http://packages.ros.org/cgi-bin/gen_rosinstall.py?rosdistro=diamondback&variant=desktop-full&overlay=no"

I first get the error message:

Unable to download URL [http://packages.ros.org/cgi-bin/gen_rosinstall.py?rosdistro=diamondback&variant=desktop-full&overlay=no]:
couldn't load config uri http://packages.ros.org/cgi-bin/gen_rosinstall.py?rosdistro=diamondback&variant=desktop-full&overlay=no
ERROR: Bad remote rosinstall source: http://packages.ros.org/cgi-bin/gen_rosinstall.py?rosdistro=diamondback&variant=desktop-full&overlay=no  This can be caused by empty or malformed remote rosinstall file.

However, I can view http://packages.ros.org/cgi-bin/gen_rosinstall.py?rosdistro=diamondback&variant=desktop-full&overlay=no in my web browser, and rosinstall actually creates the .rosinstall file in the correct directory.

When I issue the command: rosinstall ./ .rosinstall , rosinstall is able to checkout everything from code.ros.org, but throws an exception when it gets to the kforge geometry stack. Here's the error:

Installing https://kforge.ros.org/geometry/geometry geometry-1.4.2 to /home/dvenable/Documents/ROS/geometry
abort: error: Connection timed out
ERROR: Failed to install tree '/home/dvenable/Documents/ROS/geometry'
Checkout of https://kforge.ros.org/geometry/geometry version geometry-1.4.2 into /home/dvenable/Documents/ROS/geometry failed.

However I am able to view the https://kforge.ros.org/geometry/geometry website.

Issuing a manual clone: hg clone https://kforge.ros.org/geometry/geometry geometry also fails with a "Connection timed out"

Any suggestions, or is kforge just down. Tried this on the same llaptop at work and at home, so I'm guessing it's either a connection error on their end, or something's just not configured correctly. I made sure to add all the deps on the wiki:

sudo apt-get install build-essential python-yaml cmake subversion wget python-setuptools mercurial

Thanks

-DV

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10891/rosinstall-fails-when-encountering-kforge-repos-from-generated-.rosinstall-file/) by [venabled](https://answers.ros.org/users/951/venabled/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2011-08-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm able to clone the geometry repo linked above.  I suspect that kforge might have had a hiccup, or you had connection problems.  I suggest that you retry.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1